# Simple jasmine tests using enzyme is failing.

Tags: reactjs, karma-jasmine, enzyme

I am writing a simple test for a react component using enzyme to create a shallow clone which is failing when it shouldn't be. The two things I am trying to see, is if it rendered alright, and if it got a prop. Both of these are failing. Here the component I am testing and my spec:

My component:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default class PortfolioItem extends React.Component<any, any> {
  render() {
    // Deconstructing the items obj into these consts
    const {
      ID,
      abbreviation,
      active,
      managementCompany,
      name,
      targetOperatingReserve
    } = this.props.item;
    return (
      <tr className='.item'>
        <td className='id' >{ID}</td>
        <td className='abv' >{abbreviation}</td>
        <td className='active' >{active}</td>
        <td className='manComp' >{managementCompany}</td>
        <td className='name' >{name}</td>
        <td className='tor' >{targetOperatingReserve}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}
```

My Spec:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import PortfolioItem from '../../src/js/components/PortfolioItem';

const createShallowPortfolioItem = () => {
  const props = {
    item: {
      ID: 1234567,
      abbreviation: 'rit',
      active: true,
      managementCompany: false,
      name: 'Jorge Joestar',
      targetOperatingReserve: 0.0
    }
  };
  return shallow(<PortfolioItem {...props} />);
};

describe('PortfolioItem', () => {
  it('it contains the class name item', () => {
    const portItem = createShallowPortfolioItem();
    expect(portItem.is('.item')).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('renders the item name', () => {
    const item = createShallowPortfolioItem();
    expect(item.find('.name').text()).toEqual('Jorge Joestar');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"item" class is on the `tr`, your component first children not on the component itself. When rendering `PortfolioItem` you would first have a div and inside that div the children you defined in the render. That explains why the first test fail.
The second test fails because `shallow` does not create the whole component, there is no children so no element with class ".name".

So you can either use `mount` to have a full render of the component` with children. Or test something else like

```
expect(portItem).toEqual(jasmine.anything())
```

Not very fancy but if an error prevent you component from being rendered the test will fail.